# How can I disable JavaScript warnings in the WebBrowser control?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, webbrowser-control

I'm using the WebBrowser control and mshtml.dll. When I simulate click on link `<a href='..'>..</a>`, the WebBrowser shows a JavaScript warning dialog:

> Unable to move the focus to the element as it is in the invisible ,off  or can't have a focus.

The code I use to simulate the click:

```
anchor.click();
```

...where `anchor` has the type: `HTMLAnchorElementClass`

So I want to disable all JavaScript warnings in my component WebBrowser. How might I do this?

Comment: can someone with enough rep help and rewrite the OP's question to proper english for better clarity

Comment: Slightly better now, I hope! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if your referring to the windows forms [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control but it has the [ScriptErrorsSuppressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed.aspx) property for disabling script error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the place where you are doing `anchor.click();` and either remove it or replace it with `if(anchor.clientHeight != 0){anchor.click();}`.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to work around this particular warning by having the link element be part of the page and visible.

Calling the `click()` method actually does more than execute an onclick handler and navigate the browser, it also focuses the element - just like when a real click happens. If the element is offscreen, this behavior is not possible.

Simply attach the link to the body to not have this warning show up.